# How can i get a aggregate sum of Average number of product given between two weeks and output for Each week as shown below in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

| StartWeek | End Week | Numberof Week | Number of Product | Avg number of product per week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39 | 41 | 3 | 99 | 33 |
| 40 | 45 | 5 | 150 | 30 |
| 40 | 42 | 3 | 60 | 20 |
| 39 | 40 | 2 | 40 | 20 |
| 39 | 41 | 3 | 99 | 33 |

So that the output looks like --

| Week | Sum Average Product per week |
| --- | --- |
| 39 | 86 |
| 40 | 70 |
| 41 | 66 |
| 42 | 20 |
| 45 | 30 |

Comment: your question is not clear yet how did yo get for example 86 in week 39

Comment: 39 week - 33+20+33

Comment: 40 week  -30+20+20

Comment: for 40 week should it not also include a number from the first row 9as it covers week 40) and the last row 9as it also covers week 40)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First for each row we create a list of weeks that it applies to, and put in column 'weeks'

```
df['weeks'] = df.apply(lambda r: np.arange(r['StartWeek'], r['EndWeek']+1),axis=1)
```

`df` looks like this

```
      StartWeek    EndWeek    NumberofWeek    NumberofProduct    Av  weeks
--  -----------  ---------  --------------  -----------------  ----  -------------------
 0           39         41               3                 99    33  [39 40 41]
 1           40         45               5                150    30  [40 41 42 43 44 45]
 2           40         42               3                 60    20  [40 41 42]
 3           39         40               2                 40    20  [39 40]
 4           39         41               3                 99    33  [39 40 41]
```

Then we `explode` weeks which duplicates each row for each week it is applied to, and then aggregate by the exploded week and sum:

```
df.explode('weeks').groupby('weeks', as_index = False)['Av'].sum()
```

output:

```
      weeks    Av
--  -------  ----
 0       39    86
 1       40   136
 2       41   116
 3       42    50
 4       43    30
 5       44    30
 6       45    30
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `group by` method in python
`df=df.groupby(["StartWeek"])["Avg number of product per week"].sum()`